# Smart Contracts Integration in wax Cloud wallet in unity

Tags: c#, c, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I tried to get the following parameters that is shown here:

[image]

I tried by doing this :

[image]

But it's giving the errors in webgl build.

[image]

Please suggest a good way to handle it.

I tried Eos sharp sdk but it is saying that Eos is not supported on Webgl.

[image]

Please check and suggest a solution for that.please share any reference video or documentation that can help me  to come out of this problem.

Comment: Please don't Capitalize random Words. It's very Annoying to read Text Like this.

Comment: please do not include code as images. Paste the code in as text instead :)